# Is send/receive packet buffer the same preallocated memory

Tags: windows, udp, buffer-overflow

I have a windows app consuming large amounts of incoming udp traffic and sending a small number of udp packets 'keep alive' messages. I'm seeing a small amount of drops on both incoming and outgoing. I was surprised that the small amount of outgoing data was experiencing drops so I captured the packets using netMon and see them all being sent though out of the server, 3 frames sent only 2 arrive at the linux server.

I'd like to know the following:
1. Is NetMon a clone on the sock_buffer and therefore the data may be dropped at the packet buffer and not actually be being sent of the server?
2. Is the packet buffer memory the same for both send and receive (ie. if receive packet buffers are using all the buffer memory preallocated could this cause packet loss on the small amount of outgoing traffic)?

Answer (score 0):

First thing: The send and receive packet buffer have separate memory.
Second thing: NetMon works on lower network layer, not the socket layer.
third thing: Keep in mind that UDP is unreliable protocol and you can not ensure that all packets sent from one end will be received on other end. If you need reliability, you should consider TCP or some other reliable protocol.

By the way both sender and receiver are on same LAN or Internet?? How they are connected? if you can describe it then maybe someone can suggest something else to debug the issue further.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. To answer a few of your questions, yes they are on the same LAN, I'm not sure of the exact detail on how they are connected (at least one switch), and no TCP is not an option (the amount of loss is acceptable but I'd like to understand it and try and to improve it).

So if netMon captures the frames on the sending server does that mean its 100% sure they got out on the wire (no room the NIC to drop them and therefore have to be a network issue)?

Out of interest is there any good docs out there to help me understand this a bit better?
Thanks

Comment: hmm... first thing is that if both are on same LAN then there are very rare chances that your packets are dropped because of UDP unreliability. Myself I prefer using "Wireshark" (previously known as Ethreal) instead of NetMon to debug these kind of issues. And there is very very rare possibility that your packet is dropped at NIC, so there could be some other issue as well. Have you tried reducing or stopping incoming data and see if the problem is still there?? Other debugging options could be to enable logging in your switch or router for UDP and see if your outgoing packets reach there??

Comment: Also what in particular you need to understand?? I mean what kind of documentation you are looking for? UDP protocol details? or Packet Sniffing details (NetMon)?? something specific?

Comment: Again thanks....Its a hard one to pin point as it doesn't happen all the time but does generally occur a few times a day when I have one app subscribing to multiple multicast streams (where the additional multicast streams are only 10% of the original).
 
I would like to get a better understanding of how the data gets from the wire up in to userspace. The buffers involved and the rules for accessing them.